# gwt-visualization dependency dont work?

Tags: java, gwt, jakarta-ee, vaadin

I want to use the visualizationsforvaadin , and to use this i added the visualization and the gwt-visualization dependency :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
        <artifactId>visualizationsforvaadin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.gwt.google-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-visualization</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

but i get the error : Missing artifact com.google.gwt.google-apis:gwt-visualization:jar:1.1.2

Any help please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recall having the same problem. I just couldn't find the artifact from the repositories, so I downloaded it manually and added it to my local repository. Try this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gwt-visualization.jar \
-DgroupId=com.google.gwt.google-apis -DartifactId=gwt-visualization \
-Dversion=1.1.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Djavadoc=gwt-visualization-javadoc.jar
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find the jar by adding the following repository:

```
<repository>
  <id>Activiti</id>
  <url>http://maven.alfresco.com/nexus/content/repositories/activiti-thirdparty</url>
```

Answer (score 0):

The full POM says:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
   <artifactId>visualizationsforvaadin</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<repository>
   <id>vaadin-addons</id>
   <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
</repository>
```

and for gwt visualisation, the latest one I can see on mvnrepository is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.gwt.google-apis</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-visualization</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, which version of GWT are you using?

Comment: Yes i have the full pom  and im using the 2.3.0 version of gwt , the version 1.0.2 of gwt-visualization dont work with the 1.1.2 visualizationsforvaadin , so i have to use this version
    http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-visualization-1.1.2.zip&can=2&q=